# Control external audio amplifier with OS volume

Tags: audio, speakers, amplification

I have a 3.5mm audio cable running from my motherboard to speakers system which has it's own amplifier. And from what I know to get best audio quality and low interference noises I should always set my OS volume to maximum and control the volume on speakers themselves. But it is very inconvenient to always have to reach the back of my speakers to adjust the volume.

**Question:** is there any system on the market, which sets the volume on amplifier according to OS volume level? Is it possible to design such system?

I have some arduino knowledge and have a basic vision how I could get Windows volume value, send the value via Bluetooth to microcontroller receiver, replace manual potentiometer with digital potentiometer on amplifier and control amplifier volume with microcontroller. But how do I force Windows not to decrease audio signal from 3.5mm output?

Comment: What you're proposing is complete overkill on a mini-jack audio out from a PC. It's never going to be good, even with optimum gain-staging. Just walk over to the amp & use the volume knob.

Comment: If you want best audio quality, does it necessarily have to be the 3.5mm output? Most motherboards have at least one digital audio output.

Comment: @user1686 you're right, but from what I read, if you decrease the OS volume, Widows will also downscale audio signal even if it's going to a digital output

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the feedback. I agree that this is an overkill but I'm still interested in it for academic reasons

Comment: On a PC, it's not so much the bit-reduction as you turn the levels down in software, it's the hideously cheapo DACs they put on them. If you want to do this properly, first you'll need good external DACs. In the meantime, use the volume knob ;)) Unless you're starting from at least 16-bit if not 24-bit WAV, then you're wasting your time. MP3s just aren't going to feel the benefit.

Comment: Possibly just my opinion [as a professional audio engineer] but in pure price-point terms, you'll probably not start to hear the difference until your audio rig gets above the 500 - 1000 dollar range [excluding the cost of the PC itself, just the audio side].

Answer (score 1):

"But how do I force Windows not to decrease audio signal from 3.5mm output?"

You don't need to use the windows audio and there is no reason to tie it to the computer audio setting. You don't need to hook into windows audio at all, just use e.g. AutoHotkey. Whatever software you would use to signal the arduino to adjust the volume, just send it a signal i.e. if you are using TCP, autohotkey > curl request to raise volume.

In the situation you describe, you are simply using windows to turn a knob remotely, the fact that the audio is coming out of the same system is not relevant.

Probably makes more sense to just use an ir receiver on the arduino

Comment: All you're doing by adding an arduino to the equation is adding signal loss & potential distortion as you have to go through one, if not two, more encode/decode processes; unless both the PC & arduino have at least 24-bit digital i/o & you're running at least 32-bit float signal processing in it. You're still left with whatever DACs the arduino has as output. I'm just not seeing the benefit.

Comment: you misunderstand: the arduino is for controlling a volume knob. The OP describes an arduino that adjusts a digital potentiometer to control volume on  the amplifier.

Comment: Digital pot needs an ADAC somewhere. [Heath Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) & [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) would love it, increasing complexity massively, just to save a 3 yard walk ;)

Comment: I am reminded of the story about the guy who would "remote into" a PC to eject the cd tray which would actuate the reset button on another PC. Saved him from walking across campus or something.

Comment: I'm liking that idea ;)) Cracking cheese Gromit!